# Unity3d, GUI.Windows always on TOP in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Objective:

- Set GUI.Windows always on Top

i had use coding to create few GUI.Windows with C#. But i fail to make the "Windows A" always on Top. i had try to use GUI.Depth, but it seems like not working.

Is that got any way can make the "GUI.Windows" always on TOP? And even i click those area behind "Windows A", it wont make "Windows B" or "Windows C" Show on Top?

thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to:

1. leave GUI.Windows alone and simply draw your own windows (thats what I did).
2. However, if that cannot be achieved. Make sure you draw Windows A last.

In general I can recommend you to use one OnGUI and make everyone use that. You can do this by  making one OnGUI game object that handles all your GUI drawing. This is best interns of performance (less overhead) and less problems battling concurrency and order of execution problems between scripts.